# Uncaught TypeError: value.isBefore is not a function in x-date-picker, MUI, Formik & Yup

Tags: reactjs, forms, yup, formik-material-ui, multi-step

I just make a multi form with React + MUI + Formik + Yup

When I fill the second form and go next form and then back to second form console show the following error and also browser screen goes to white
[Console Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWMXi.png)

and Here is the code of my second form

```
import { TextField, Button, Grid, FormHelperText } from "@mui/material";
import { Container } from "@mui/system";
import { FieldArray, Form, Formik, getIn } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { DatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  education: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      institution: Yup.string().required("Insitution is required"),
      degree: Yup.string().required("Degree is required"),
      city: Yup.string().required("City is required"),
      cgpa: Yup.number()
        .typeError("CGPA must be a number")
        .max(4.0, "CGPA cannot exceed 4.0")
        .required("CGPA is Required"),
      date: Yup.date().required("Date is required").typeError("Valid Date"),
    })
  ),
});

const Education = ({ data, next, back }) => {
  const handleSubmit = (vals) => {
    next(vals);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Formik
        initialValues={data}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        {({
          handleBlur,
          handleChange,
          errors,
          touched,
          values,
          setFieldValue,
        }) => (
          <Form>
            <FieldArray
              name="education"
              render={({ push, remove }) => (
                <>
                  {values.education.map((_, index) => (
                    <Container maxWidth="md" key={index} sx={{ mt: "30px" }}>
                      <Grid container spacing={2}>
                        <Grid item lg={6} xs={12} sx={{ py: 4 }}>
                          <TextField
                            sx={{ width: "100%", backgroundColor: "white" }}
                            name={`education[${index}].institution`}
                            label="Institution"
                            value={values.institution}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            error={
                              touched.education?.[index]?.institution &&
                              Boolean(errors.education?.[index]?.institution)
                            }
                          />
                          {touched.education?.[index]?.institution &&
                            errors.education?.[index]?.institution && (
                              <FormHelperText
                                sx={{
                                  color: "#d32f2f",
                                }}
                              >
                                {errors.education[index].institution}
                              </FormHelperText>
                            )}
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item lg={6} xs={12} sx={{ py: 4 }}>
                          <TextField
                            sx={{ width: "100%", backgroundColor: "white" }}
                            name={`education[${index}].degree`}
                            label="Degree"
                            value={values.education[index].degree}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            type="text"
                            error={
                              touched.education?.[index]?.degree &&
                              Boolean(errors.education?.[index]?.degree)
                            }
                          />
                          {touched.education?.[index]?.degree &&
                            errors.education?.[index]?.degree && (
                              <FormHelperText
                                sx={{
                                  color: "#d32f2f",
                                }}
                              >
                                {errors.education[index].degree}
                              </FormHelperText>
                            )}
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item lg={6} xs={12} sx={{ py: 4 }}>
                          <TextField
                            sx={{ width: "100%", backgroundColor: "white" }}
                            name={`education[${index}].city`}
                            label="City"
                            value={values.education[index].city}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            type="text"
                            error={
                              touched.education?.[index]?.city &&
                              Boolean(errors.education?.[index]?.city)
                            }
                          />
                          {touched.education?.[index]?.city &&
                            errors.education?.[index]?.city && (
                              <FormHelperText
                                sx={{
                                  color: "#d32f2f",
                                }}
                              >
                                {errors.education[index].city}
                              </FormHelperText>
                            )}
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item lg={6} xs={12} sx={{ py: 4 }}>
                          <TextField
                            sx={{ width: "100%", backgroundColor: "white" }}
                            name={`education[${index}].cgpa`}
                            label="cgpa"
                            value={values.education[index].cgpa}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            type="text"
                            error={
                              touched.education?.[index]?.cgpa &&
                              Boolean(errors.education?.[index]?.cgpa)
                            }
                          />
                          {touched.education?.[index]?.cgpa &&
                            errors.education?.[index]?.cgpa && (
                              <FormHelperText
                                sx={{
                                  color: "#d32f2f",
                                }}
                              >
                                {errors.education[index].cgpa}
                              </FormHelperText>
                            )}
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item lg={6} xs={12} sx={{ py: 4 }}>
                          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                            <DatePicker
                              label="Select Date"
                              format="MM/DD/YYYY"
                              name={`education[${index}].date`}
                              sx={{ width: "100%", backgroundColor: "white" }}
                              value={values.education[index].date}
                              onBlur={handleBlur}
                              onChange={(value) => {
                                const year = value.year();
                                const month = String(
                                  value.month() + 1
                                ).padStart(2, "0");
                                const day = String(value.date()).padStart(
                                  2,
                                  "0"
                                );
                                const formattedDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
                                setFieldValue(
                                  `education[${index}].date`,
                                  formattedDate
                                );
                              }}
                              slotProps={{
                                textField: {
                                  error: Boolean(
                                    getIn(errors, `education[${index}].date`) &&
                                      getIn(touched, `education[${index}].date`)
                                  ),
                                  helperText: (
                                    <FormHelperText
                                      sx={{
                                        // color: "#d32f2f",
                                        fontSize: "12px",
                                        backgroundColor: "transparent",
                                        margin: "0",
                                      }}
                                    >
                                      {getIn(
                                        errors,
                                        `education[${index}].date`,
                                        ""
                                      )}
                                    </FormHelperText>
                                  ),
                                },
                              }}
                            />
                          </LocalizationProvider>
                        </Grid>
                        {values.education.length > 1 && (
                          <Grid item>
                            <Button
                              type="button"
                              variant="outlined"
                              onClick={() => remove(index)}
                            >
                              Remove
                            </Button>
                          </Grid>
                        )}
                        {index === values.education.length - 1 && (
                          <Grid item>
                            <Button
                              type="button"
                              variant="contained"
                              onClick={() =>
                                push({
                                  institution: "",
                                  degree: "",
                                  city: "",
                                  cgpa: "",
                                  date: null,
                                })
                              }
                            >
                              Add More
                            </Button>
                          </Grid>
                        )}
                      </Grid>
                    </Container>
                  ))}
                </>
              )}
            />
            <Container maxWidth="md" sx={{ pt: "16px" }}>
              <Grid container>
                <Grid
                  item
                  xs={12}
                  sx={{
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "end",
                    gap: "20px",
                  }}
                >
                  <Button type="button" variant="outlined" onClick={back}>
                    Back
                  </Button>
                  <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
                    Next
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Container>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </>
  );
};

export default Education;
```

So I want to remove the error and fix the issue and I just search about it but not get the proper solution.